# what did printf do here?

Tags: c, printf, integer-overflow

Just i was testing my understanding of pointers, while doing so i did this,

Okay this is what i think.
All pointers to any type hold addresses, right?
Say i declare
`char *a, b = 'f';
 a = &b ;`
So when i try to access content of b that is &b, through a pointer to type char.which is okay.

But, What if i store address of int data type in a pointer of char type(although i get warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types], i'm not doing wrong, right?.i'm still storing address of some memory.)

```
int main(){
// int type of one byte
    int a, i ;
    char *b;

    for(i = -256 ;i < 257; ++i){
        a = i;
        b = &a;
        printf("for i = %d, value stored in first byte of a = %d\n",i ,*b);
    }
    return 0;    
}
```

now i thought that it will be allowed to read only first byte of 4 bytes allocated to ***a*** because i'm accessing through a pointer to a char type, i was expecting to store values up to 255, beyond this will be kind of overflow.

but it happened something different i could only store 127 to -128 whao!!.Did you see it a type int of size one byte.You can run code to see.

**Now assume that int type is of size one byte**

when a = 256, value read is 0, which is expected, because 0001 0000 0000 it will read only first byte.
Output is predictable until we reach a = 127, which is stored as 0111 1111  (which is positive value from type int perspective)
when a = 128, output is -128 , which is stored 1000 0000 (which is indeed -128)
similarly other outputs can be explained
So output can be explained by assuming that int type is of size one byte, **why did printf do that instead of throwing error.**

So what exactly did printf do here?
**Thank you excellencies ;)**

Comment: note that your code is endian dependent too

Comment: `a  = &b;` (or `b = &a;` in the program later) is a constraint violation -- this is not allowed. You can use `-Werror` compiler flag to get an error message .

Comment: It would be less confusing if your first paragraph used the same variable names as the program

Comment: @M.M: Constraint violations are allowed. The C standard requires C implementations to diagnose them. It does not require C implementations to prohibit them and does permit C implementations to successfully translate programs containing constraint violations.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The standard *does not* require the implementation to translate a program with a constraint violation, so I describe this as "not allowed". In your terminology almost everything would be "allowed" (either because it's correct, or because the standard places no requirements on the behaviour of programs containing constraint violations or other undefined behaviour), therefore such terminology is useless

Comment: @M.M: Even if we accept your argument that “allowed” is useless in this sense (it omits something, but it is not important at the moment), that does not prove that “not allowed” is useful. In fact, it is not, both because it is false and because it leads people to a faulty understanding of the C standard. The C standard defines only a core language and it is intended for the language to be extended, and it must be extended to be of more than minimal use. People should not be told that doing things beyond what the standard requires is not allowed. You can say it is not defined by the standard.

Comment: It's true that it is not allowed by the standard in a conforming program . I use informal language for people who aren't experts in the standard's terminology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But, What if i store address of int data type in a pointer of char type(although i get warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types], i'm not doing wrong, right?.i'm still storing address of some memory.)

Yeah, you’re doing something wrong, which is why you get the warning.

Pointer type *matters* for two reasons:

1. Pointer arithmetic is done in terms of objects, not bytes.  If `p` is a `char *` and its value is the address of a `char` object (say `0x1000`), then `p + 1` evaluates to the address of the next `char` object (`0x1001`).  If `p` is an `int *` and its value is the address of a 4-byte `int` object (`0x2000`), the  `p + 1` evaluates to the address of the next 4-byte `int` object (`0x2004`).
2. Like other types, different pointer types may have different sizes and representations.  An `int *` may have a different representation from a `char *`.  On most modern systems like x86 and x86_64 they’re the same, but there are some older or oddball architectures where that’s not the case.

> So output can be explained by assuming that int type is of size one byte, why did printf do that instead of throwing error.

The issue isn't with `printf`, the issue is that you're encountering *signed integer overflow* when you attempt to assign `128` to `*b`, since on your system plain `char` occupies the range `[-128..127]`.  Unfortunately, the behavior on signed integer overflow is *undefined* - there's no requirement that your implementation handle it in any particular way.  Most implementations that I'm aware of don't try to handle it at all - you just get an unexpected value.  Given that there are multiple signed integer representations, and given that many implementations rely on that undefined behavior to perform certain optimizations, you could get pretty much *any* result.

Answer (score 4):

Your system uses signed characters, which is totally normal.

You seem to assume/expect `char` to be `unsigned`, which is not always true. It is either signed or unsigned, but that depends on the implementation.

Comment: @EricPostpischil True, I was oversimplifying a bit. I dropped the code markdown maybe that helps. Thanks.